# How to get data through a specific pod use with this (<pod-name>.<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local) Url?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, kubernetes, asp.net-web-api, minikube

I have Two projects asp .net core Api and asp .net core MVC. In the asp .net core Api have a Two Replicas(instance) and asp .net core MVC have a three Replicas(instances).

so i try to connect api pod to mvc with this "(pod-name).(service-name).(namespace).svc.cluster.local" url to get data form api but this url is not working.

this is my api project cmd runner:
the api is run with port-forwading like this "kubectl port-forward pod/webapiservice2-1 8081:80" the api data is get successfully.

[image]

this is my asp.net core mvc project code:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetMySqlData()
        {
            
            var Baseurl = "http://webapiservice2-1.webapiservice2.default.svc.cluster.local:8081";
            
            List<Customer> EmpInfo = new List<Customer>();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

                //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("/home/mysqldata");

                //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                    var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                    EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(EmpResponse);

                }
                //returning the employee list to view  
                return View(EmpInfo);

            }

        }
```

in this code the url is "http://webapiservice2-1.webapiservice2.default.svc.cluster.local:8081" there are not working. the pod data is not get from the api.

when i run this mvc the error is:
" HttpRequestException: Name or service not known (webapiservice2-0.webapiservice2.default.svc.cluster.local:8081) "